# Add contact for Impersonation Account

Tags: php, exchange-server, contacts

I'm using https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews for Exchange Web Services and I'm having a problem adding a contact for an account.

When I login using my impersonation details:

```
$ews = new ExchangeWebServices($this->server_address, $this->server_username, $this->server_password);
```

I want to create a new contact, e.g.:

```
    $request = new EWSType_CreateItemType();
    $contact = new EWSType_ContactItemType();
    $contact->Initials = $this->relation->initials;
    $contact->GivenName = $this->relation->first_name;
    $contact->MiddleName = $this->relation->insertion;
    $contact->Surname = $this->relation->last_name;
    $request->Items->Contact[] = $contact;
    $result = $ews->CreateItem($request);
```

I want to add this contact to a account that exists in my impersonation account list.

I want to avoid directly login in as an exchange user like:

```
    $ews = new ExchangeWebServices($this->server_address, 'some@outlook.account', 'somepassword');
```

Is this possible? How would I achieve such a thing? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you most away from james's php-ews, it's unmaintained and doesn't follow any of the PSR's. I'd suggest you take a look at my own fork, [`garethp/php-ews`](https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews). Creating a contact would be rather similar, but impersonation is made easy by my fork (example [here](https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews/blob/master/examples/basic/impersonation.php)) and if that's not working for you, you can always drop me a Github issue and I'll try to help out

Comment: I will surely check that out!